# Смена контента без обновления странички

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Добрый день!

Встретился с такой проблемкой, и надеюсь на вашу помощь:
На страничке хочется реализовать смену контента без обновления странички. Все легко реализовал через AJAX (*с index.php через AJAX обращался к test.php с GET параметрами*)
Все работает.

НО потом всплыла проблема: тот текст который я получал, на него не работает JS (*сразу оговорю тот момент, что если этот текст вбить напрямую, не выводом через AJAX - то все работает*). В интернете довольно популярная такая проблемка. Вот надеюсь на вашу любую помощь, подскажите как можно генерировать текст из test.php, в index.php без обновления, чтобы на него действовали JS.

Comment: мммм там для определенных как я понял функций, я если на сами скрипты , например мне нужно 2: jquery.js, jcarousellite.js

Comment: Нет, тут я как лингвист пас. Можете более простым языком пояснить значение набора слов выше. Можно с примерами, чтоб наверняка.

Comment: <head>тут JS</head>
<body><div id="test"></div></body>
<тут кнопка>
/////
Когда нажимаю на кнопку появляется целый блог (можно сказать пол сайта), а для этого блога, нужны JS, которые прописаны в head, если этот блог сразу вставить без кнопки - все работает, если через кнопку то уже проблемы. не видит JS.

Comment: Кто кого не видит-то? Загруженный контент не видит подключённые в head библиотеки или подключённые в head библиотеки не видят загруженный контент?

Comment: загруженный контент не видит подключенные библиотеки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если имеется ввиду, что на загруженный контент не распространяются обработчики событий, то решение - вешать обработчики при помощи [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/live/). В этом случае обработчики, повешенные до загрузки контента, будут работать и на загруженном контенте.

Answer (score 0):

Используя делегирования событий. В самом простом случае вешать обработчик прямо на  body, если не волнует особо производительность.

```
 $('body').on('click', 'селектор контейнера с текстом', function() {...});
```